# I want to print the meta_value of all with the key "post_views_count" from the post_meta table

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to print (meta_value) from all fields
"Post_views_count" from  table (post_meta) But provided that this happens in every category.
I want to count every visit inaide selected category , and in the end appear the name of category and every category generate visitors inside it .
This is the code that i used it and work good but the page are too slowly due to recurrent queries

```
    <?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0,
  'depth' => 0
  );
  // Extract all categories
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
// Extract all posts within each category
$args = array(
                    'cat' => $category->term_id,
                    'orderby' =>'post_date',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // Views variable
                $allview_cat = 0;


                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $posttype = get_post_type(get_the_ID());
            
                         while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            
                            $query->the_post();
                            $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;


            // Query that extracts all fields containing post_views_count + post id
            $post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'post_views_count' AND post_id = $post->ID );");
            
            $post_id = array_map(function($item){
        
            return $item->{'meta_value'};
        
            }
            ,$post_id);

            
            foreach($post_id as $m_key => $m_value) {
                
                    
                    
                    $allview_cat = $m_value + $allview_cat ."<br>";
                    
                }

} // end while
            
            
 } // end if

 // Views variable 
 echo $allview_cat;
}
 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please use a bit of punctuation when you are describing your problem, and not just write one sentence after the other without any commas or periods in between. That is hard to read.

Comment: And proper indentation would make your code easier to read as well.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to improve the question

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent' => 0,
        'depth' => 0
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $cat_id = $category->term_id;
        $args_post = array(
            'cat' => $cat_id,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args_post );

        $allview = array();

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                if ( !isset( $allview[$cat_id] ) {
                   $allview[$cat_id] = 0;
                }
                $post_views_count = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_views_count' );

                $allview[$cat_id] = (int)$allview[$cat_id] + (int)$post_views_count;
            }
        }
    }

    //display results
    foreach ( $allview as $cat => $value ) {
        echo $cat . ' = ' . $value;
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: When running, it produces an error on this line

$allview[$cat_id] = $allview[$cat_id] + $post_views_count;

Comment: @أحمدالكدي Can you give a error message?

Comment: This is an image of the error message

https://prnt.sc/26dx80i

Comment: I updated code, please check

Comment: The problem still appears in this line     
$allview[$cat_id] = $allview[$cat_id] + $post_views_count;
      https://prnt.sc/26e6u9u

Comment: I updated code again, please check